Blazor wasm app not updating on refresh in development when non-c# changes are made in razor files
I have to stop the debugger and restart to see even the simplest changes (such as simply changing a text value in a <p> tag) to razor files.
I currently have it setup so that server pre-renders the page and it does reflect updates but when the wasm app is loaded after a couple seconds then it reverts back.
Hard refresh of the page doesn't help even when clearing the cache. I can only see the changes in the wasm app after stopping and restarting the debugger.
It's very frustrating and time consuming to have to restart the application to see every little html/css change I make.
Trying to find out if this is a known issue, or if there is some setting or something I have to switch on or off?
EDIT:
So if I make a change to the razor.css file then it does immediately reflect the update on save. Very strange that this works, but that a simple text change on the razor page doesn't get updated without a restart.

Hot Reload for .NET supports all types of .NET apps built in Visual Studio and enables you to apply changes to your code directly against the running app without having to restart.
Tips and Tricks: Hot Reload for ASP.NET Core Blazor


I use hot reload. It works on other projects and it acts like it's working in this Blazor project, but it doesn't. If you know how to make it work please let me know.

@BVernon It's hard for us to check this specific issue, unless you can provide a minimal sample(create a brand new sample can protect your data safe) for us, then we can investigate the issue further, thanks for your understanding.

I understand. I was hoping there was perhaps a common issue or set of common issues that had been identified which might be causing the problem, but it sounds like that's not the case. If I create a new project, it works. So then I would have to start migrating the existing project in a piece at a time until I see what's causing the issue which would be very time consuming, followed by undoing that work and recreating just the actual problem so I can share it. I do intend to do this, but just pointing out why it won't be forthcoming very soon as I have to have the time to do it.
